# Desktop of 1080p external display only covers a quater of screen [Using xrandr]

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, arch-linux, manjaro, xrandr

I used to use Ubuntu for my development environment, as I have a new workstation I have decided to switch to Manjaro, with a KDE GUI.

When I used Gnome, I used a tool named [xrandr-extend](https://github.com/ashwinvis/xrandr-extend) in order to grant me the ability of using both my laptop 4k screen and my external 1080p screen without suffering from the usual scaling issues. It worked fine; I had no problems with xrandr-extend on Gnome. On Manjaro, however, I am inflicted with an issue I cannot resolve.

The issue lies in the desktop on the external display:

[image: External display desktop]

As you can see three-quarters of the display is black, while the desktop accommodates the last quarter of the screen.

I do think it may have something to do with the fact I am compressing the screen by 2 in the xrandr-extend config. I'm doing this to achieve the optimal degree of scaling to use applications on the screen. However, if this is the case, then how can I retain the level of scaling I need while having the entire desktop instance on the external display span the entire width and length of said display?

To my knowledge, I have populated the configuration file correctly:

```
[provider:modesetting]
primary = eDP-1
hdmi = HDMI-1
vga = DP-1

[provider:nouveau]
primary = eDP1
hdmi = HDMI1
vga = DP1

[resolutions]
primary = 3840, 2180
hdmi = 1920, 1080
vga = 1920, 1200

[scaling]
hdmi =  2
```

The console logs generated when I execute the command to extend and scale the external display:

```
[dukejm@duke-pc ~]$ xrandr-extend -n hdmi                 
xrandr --auto
xrandr --listmonitors
xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --panning 3840x2160+3840+0 --scale 2.0x2.0 --right-of eDP1
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP1 3840/350x2160/190+0+0  eDP1
 1: +HDMI1 1920/530x1080/300+3840+0  HDMI1
[dukejm@duke-pc ~]$ xrandr-extend -n hdmi
xrandr --auto
xrandr --listmonitors
xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --panning 3840x2160+3840+0 --scale 2.0x2.0 --right-of eDP1
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP1 3840/350x2160/190+0+0  eDP1
 1: +HDMI1 3840/530x2160/300+3840+0  HDMI1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact same problem in KDE Manjaro and I hoped this problem is going to be fixed in following releases, but this is going for more than 1 year.

I also used the *xrandr* solution in the form:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --scale 2x2
```

I could get used to only a quarter of background, but there is an even worse caveat to this story. Anything that is only in the dark region works at **1 fps** and it is therefore unusable. Only if the window is at least partially in the quarter displayed area, it behaves normally.